# "find" method for dictionary project for ruby / rspec

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary, rspec

I'm new to ruby and am working on a dictionary project that needs to pass Rspec, and I'm running into a bit of trouble with implementing a required "find" method.

The specifications are as follows:

```
require 'dictionary'

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
  end

  it "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false # if the method is empty, this test passes with nil returned
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fish').should be_true # confirms that it actually checks
    @d.include?('bird').should be_false # confirms not always returning true after add
  end

  it "doesn't include a prefix that wasn't added as a word in and of itself" do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fi').should be_false
  end

  it "doesn't find a word in empty dictionary" do
    @d.find('fi').should be_empty # {}
  end

  it 'finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing' do
    @d.add('fiend')
    @d.add('great')
    @d.find('nothing').should be_empty
  end

  it "finds an entry" do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
  end

  it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
    @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
    @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
  end

  it 'lists keywords alphabetically' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.keywords.should == %w(apple fish zebra)
  end

  it 'can produce printable output like so: [keyword] "definition"' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.printable.should == %Q{[apple] "fruit"\n[fish] "aquatic animal"\n[zebra] "African land animal with stripes"}
  end
end
```

What I have written so far is

```
class Dictionary < Hash

    def add(definition)
        definition = {definition => nil} unless definition.kind_of?(Hash)
        merge!(definition)
    end

    alias_method :entries, :dup

    def keywords
        keys.sort 
    end

    def find(definition)
        return{}

    end

end
```

I'm really at a loss as how to proceed further.  My find method passes the "doesn't find a word in empty dictionary"  and the 'finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing' portion of the test, though I am not quite sure why.  I am currently stuck on

```
  it "finds an entry" do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
  end
```

I have just started learning ruby about 5 days ago, so there are still many keywords and syntax that I don't know how to utilize.  If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, and if there is a better way to implement this method, it would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To pass in this spec you should simply return what you have added on your other method. Assuming that you implemented the `add` method, I believe the problem is that you don't know how to call the `[]` method on your context instead of in a variable. You can do like this:

```
self[definition]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I used your suggestion and some others and now it's working. Thanks again!